# Perl regular expression replace string with a substring of the regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, substring

I have a question concerning Perl.

Assume I have the following line in my file:

```
DoMatchLong ( "ThisIsMyVariable", lThisIsMyVariable);
```

I want to replace "ThisIsMyVariable" by cp_const_ThisIsMyVariable

So my aim is:

```
DoMatchLong (  cp_const_ThisIsMyVariable, lThisIsMyVariable);


$count = s/(?<=")\w+(?=")/const_cmd_cp_$&/gx;
```

leads to `DoMatchLong (  "cp_const_ThisIsMyVariable", lThisIsMyVariable)`;

So what is the correct solution?

Answer (score 5):

```
$count = s/"(\w+)"/const_cmd_cp_$1/gx;
```

Pull the quotes into the match, then use a capturing group to get only the actual text between the quotes, while still replacing them.

Comment: Thank you very much! You answered faster than I understood your solution. I like the possibility of grouping regexpes!

Comment: You probably should mark the question as answered if you've tried the solution and it works for you